# Isolate String by JSON Attribute

Tags: python, csv, twitterapi-python

I'm building a twitter scraper that writes the search term to column 1 of a CSV and tweet search results to column 2. I've built the basic API function:

```
def search_twitter(query, tweet_fields, bearer_token = BEARER_TOKEN):
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(bearer_token)}

    url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query={}&{}".format(
        query, tweet_fields
    )
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

    print(response.status_code)

    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(response.status_code, response.text)
    return response.json()
```

and below is the code that's writing the called data to a CSV file.

```
terms = ["example", "search terms", "go", "here"]

with open("urls.csv", "w") as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)
    writer.writerow(["Search Term", "Tweet"])
    json_response = search_twitter(query=t, tweet_fields=tweet_fields, bearer_token=BEARER_TOKEN)
    json.dumps(json_response, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
    for term in terms:
        writer.writerow([t, tweet])
```

The problem is I'm getting the entire JSON dump of all tweets resulting from a call.

CVS output
[image: See CVS output here]

I would like to isolate the tweet itself so that it's the only text in the cell, and I'd like to make a new row for each resulting tweet.

It should look like this:
[image: this]
Here's what the JSON structure looks like:

```
{'data': [{'id': '1438153647167311877', 'text': 'SEO For eCommerce: On-Page Optimization Comrade Digital Marketing Agency Chicago '}, {'id': '1438134464471699464', 'text': "yeonjun wearing that white top with suspenders  i just can't unsee seo hwiyoung from chicago typewriter"}, {'id': '1438074630191812608', 'text': '@bertanyarl Bule chicago nyasar ke korea nder. Namanya Seo Young Ho (서영호) alias Johnny. \nBukan bolen pisang itu, roti sobek.'}, {'id': '1437997374924890120', 'text': 'RT @getcodescandy: Geeks UI - Create Online Learning Marketplace. Responsive #bootstrap 5 theme.\n\n#ShareWhatYouKnow #teachable #Developer #…'}, {'id': '1437997352808292352', 'text': 'Geeks UI - Create Online Learning Marketplace. Responsive #bootstrap 5 theme.\n\n#ShareWhatYouKnow #teachable #Developer #Javascript #Programmer #webdev #webdesign #udemy #Chicago #Denver #Phoenix #USA #reactjs  #SEO #DigitalMarketing #codecademy #web '}, {'id': '1437966952220090370', 'text': 'RT @getcodescandy: Geeks UI - Create Online Learning Marketplace. Responsive #bootstrap 5 theme.\n\n#ShareWhatYouKnow #teachable #Developer #…'}, {'id': '1437966937850454016', 'text': 'RT @getcodescandy: Geeks UI - Create Online Learning Marketplace. Responsive #bootstrap 5 theme.\n\n#ShareWhatYouKnow #teachable #Developer #…'}, {'id': '1437966896008101889', 'text': 'RT @getcodescandy: Geeks UI - Create Online Learning Marketplace. Responsive #bootstrap 5 theme.\n\n#ShareWhatYouKnow #teachable #Developer #…'}, {'id': '1437966869579796480', 'text': 'RT @getcodescandy: Geeks UI - Create Online Learning Marketplace. Responsive #bootstrap 5 theme.\n\n#ShareWhatYouKnow #teachable #Developer #…'}, {'id': '1437966827468967937', 'text': 'RT @getcodescandy: Geeks UI - Create Online Learning Marketplace. Responsive #bootstrap 5 theme.\n\n#ShareWhatYouKnow #teachable #Developer #…'}], 'meta': {'newest_id': '1438153647167311877', 'oldest_id': '1437966827468967937', 'result_count': 10, 'next_token': 'b26v89c19zqg8o3fpdp974bw8xlzc9l3bnaj4ozavctj1'}}
```

Any help would be so appreciated!! Thanks so much

Comment: What is `terms` in `for term in terms:`?

Comment: and what is `tweet` in `[t, tweet]`?

Answer (score 0):

You need something like as follows:

```
import csv

terms = ["example", "search terms", "go", "here"]

with open("urls.csv", "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)
    writer.writerow(["Search Term", "Tweet"])
    
    for term in terms:
        json_response = search_twitter(query=term, tweet_fields=tweet_fields, bearer_token=BEARER_TOKEN)
    
        for entry in json_response['data']:
            tweet = entry['text']
            tweet_lower = tweet.lower()
        
            if term in tweet_lower:
                writer.writerow([term, tweet])
```

This reads the list from the `data` item in the JSON. It then extracts the `text` item holding the tweet and compares it with each of your terms (`lower()` is used to make it case insensitive).

You would also probably need to encode the file with `utf-8`.

**File location**

The output file `urls.csv` should be located in your current working directory. This can be shown using:

```
import os

print(os.getcwd())
```

If you want, you could force the output to be in the same folder as the script using:

```
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for the help! I'm getting a KeyError on the like where the 'data' item is requested. I'm not familiar with how to access items in JSON, is there something i'm missing here?

Comment: Your JSON structure is probably a bit different to what I could see. I'd need to know what `json_response` looks like, I was basing it on your CSV screenshot. You could do `print(json_response)` and copy / paste some of the output into your question.

Comment: I've added that bit. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: I've added it now, sorry about that.

Comment: The code should work fine for that JSON, is it possibly different sometimes? Add the print before the loop and when it fails you should see if  it is different

Comment: I've uploaded a new question as the topic has changed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69197661/twitter-scraper-not-writing-to-csv